# Android 8.1 Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds!!! apk crash

Tags: java, android, sdk, google-mobile-ads

My Android Studio version 3.4.1, I am trying to add MobileAds code into my project built with sdk 28, but getting crash report. I don't know why????

I have checked all the similar posts but some of are outdated and unfortunately could not get any solution

**My Android Manifest is**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
    android:value="true"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
        <activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

**MainActivity Layout**

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_weight="1"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
```

**App build.gradle**

```
   android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 28
multiDexEnabled true
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.txt'
}
}
repositories {
jcenter()
mavenCentral()  // GPUImage for Android
}
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
productFlavors {
}
} 
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/ormlite-android-4.43.jar')
implementation files('libs/ormlite-core-4.43.jar')
// If you want to use the GPU Filters
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_new);
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
try{

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (admov_status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(admov_status.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}catch (RuntimeException e){
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

**But still the ERROR is running. Error logcat details here**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: Link to *
* find your app ID.                                                          *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: Link to *
* find your app ID.                                                          *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabh.attachInfo(Unknown Source:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
        ... 10 more
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ad ids in Admob.

1). appID

2). adUnitID

For an app whatever the your ad type you use, the **appID** is same. But the the **adUnitID** differs for the each ad type you use. For example, you can have both banner ads and interstitial ads in the App. For both of those ad types **appID** is same, but the **adUnitID** differs.

As per your code you have used the same ID everywhere, which is not correct. You need to use **appID, adUnitID** in appropriate places. In layout xml, where you declare the ad unit it should have **adUnitID** and other places **appID**.

Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value=**appID**/>
```

MainActivity Layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_weight="1"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId=**adUnitID**>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, **appID**);
```

So in your case, it seems that you have used **adUnitID** for the the places you should have used **appID**. That's probably why it throws the error as in

```
******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: Link to *
* find your app ID.                                                          *
******************************************************************************
```

Refer this [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431?hl=en) on how to find out **appID** and **adUnitID** for your adMob

Comment: AppID can be found in AdMob UI, apps=>select your app=>App settings=>AppID

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, struggling to understand the above answer, then I tried few hit & try and it worked, later I understood the above answer.
So I am putting my observation & experience with graphical representation, to make it easy to integrate

Steps to follow:

- Create a `AdMob` Account If you don't have (https://apps.admob.com/signup/)
- Create an App going to the left Panel & providing required details asked there **(Refer Image - 1)**

> **Image - 1**

[image]

- Once asked details are given, you will see a screen like given in  **Image - 2**

> **Image - 2**

[image]

- Then you can go for adding "AD Unit" or click "Done". (If you click Done You will be redirected to AppOverview page, there you can Add "AD Unit").
- Now Click on App -> View All Apps (Again **Refer Image -1**, to see the option)
- Then You will be redirected to a page where all Apps info will be shown **(Refer Image - 3)**

> **Image - 3**

[image]

- Click on the AppId shown there, Thats your App Id. Copy that and Paste in the Manifest file in the value string as shown below, you can also refer the **Image -4**

> **Image -4**

[image]

```
           <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-8623492450664484~4654380864">
```

- Then go to your Activity.xml file (Where you added the Ad Mob banner), and add the `"Ad Unit Id"`as shown below

  ```
          <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
           android:id="@+id/adView"
           android:layout_width="416dp"
           android:layout_height="52dp"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"
           ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
           tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
  ```

If you want to test, use "AdUnitId" as mentioned below (suggested by AdMob developer document)

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

Then add the following two line in your corresponding Activity (Kotlin File)

```
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView?.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Now run the App, you will see the Ad Banner. Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer for you, but might help others:

Dynamic Feature modules cause problems when you don't include the dependency in the base build.gradle (app) file too (only dynamic manifest isn't enough).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After doing the above recommendation I also added

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()  // GPUImage for Android
}
```

in the `build.gradle` file and then the problem was resolved. Also, make sure to use `application Id` in the manifest and not `UnitId`.